# Collecting and summarising values( troubles navigating through multiple IIFEs)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm making a simple budget app project as a first JS project. I'm using a 3 main segments structure with 1 budget controller that contains my values and budgeting functions, 1 UI controller, and one global controller that deals with the exchange of info between the IIFEs. I am struggling to get the info from the input, calculate and store the value.

If the code below is not clear enough the whole file can be checked on https://github.com/treneff/Budget-app.git

The exact problem is that when I press on the input button my end savings value does not summarise, but takes always takes on the previous input value. I have the function, but I can't seem to be calculating it properly.

```
   ctrlAddPot = () => {

let potInput = UICtrl.getPotInput();
if (potInput.value > 0) {
  let addPot = budgetCtrl.addInputPot(potInput.value);

  console.log(addPot);

  UICtrl.addPotItem(addPot);
  UICtrl.clearFields();
  //calculate the budget
  updateBudget();
  }
}

 getPotInput: () => {
  return {
    value: parseFloat(document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputPot).value),
  };
},


 getBudget: () => {
  return {
    budget: data.budget,
    totalInc: data.totals.inc,
    totalExp: data.totals.exp,
    totalPot: data.pot,
    };
   },
 };

  calculateBudget: () => {
  
  calculateTotal('exp');
  calculateTotal('inc');
  calculatePotTotal();
 
  data.budget = data.totals.inc - data.totals.exp - data.totals.pot;
},

 //I Believe THE PROBLEM IS HERE, BUT THERE COULD BE SOMETHING 
// ELSE WRONG IN the function that later executes the addInputPot
addInputPot: (val) => {
  let returnAddPot = data.pot;
  data.pot = val;
  return returnAddPot;
},

let data = {
allItems: {
  exp: [],
  inc: [],
},
totals: {
  exp: 0,
  inc: 0,
  pot: 0,
},
budget: 0,
pot: 0,
};

calculatePotTotal = (value) => {

let sumPot = 0;
data.pot[value]((cur) => {
  sumPot += cur.value;
});
data.totals = sumPot;
};
```

Comment: Of course.. I never said. My original post is updated so everyone can see clearly the problem. Thanks for that !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the bug was in generated unique ID. You have the following code there:

```
if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {
    ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id = 1;
} else {
    ID = 0;
}
```

I have replaced it with:

```
ID = Date.now();
```

```js
const budgetController = (() => {
  const Expense = function (id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  };

  const Income = function (id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  };

  calculateTotal = (type) => {
    let sum = 0;
    data.allItems[type].forEach((cur) => {
      sum += cur.value;
    });
    data.totals[type] = sum;
  };
  let data = {
    allItems: {
      exp: [],
      inc: [],
    },
    totals: {
      exp: 0,
      inc: 0,
    },
    budget: 0,
  };

  return {
    addItem: (type, des, val) => {
      let newItem, ID;

      // create new ID
      ID = Date.now();
      //create a new ITEM based on type
      if (type === "exp") {
        newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
      } else if (type === "inc") {
        newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
      }
      // push it into the data structure
      data.allItems[type].push(newItem);

      //return the new element
      return newItem;
    },

    deleteItem: (type, id) => {
      let ids, index;
      ids = data.allItems[type].map((current) => {
        return current.id;
      });
      index = ids.indexOf(id);

      if (index !== -1) {
        data.allItems[type].splice(index, 1);
      }
    },

    calculateBudget: () => {
      //calculate total income and expenses
      calculateTotal("exp");
      calculateTotal("inc");

      //calculate the budget: income - expenses
      data.budget = data.totals.inc - data.totals.exp;
    },
    getBudget: () => {
      return {
        budget: data.budget,
        totalInc: data.totals.inc,
        totalExp: data.totals.exp,
      };
    },
  };
})();

//UI CONTROLLER
const UIController = (function () {
  const DOMStrings = {
    inputType: ".add-type",
    inputDescription: ".add-description",
    inputValue: ".add-value",
    inputBtn: ".add-btn ",
    incomeContainer: ".income-list",
    expensesContainer: ".expenses-list",
    budgetLabel: ".budget-value",
    incomeLabel: ".budget-income-value",
    expensesLabel: ".budget-expenses-value",
    container: ".container-main",
    dateLabel: ".budget-title-month",
  };
  return {
    getInput: () => {
      return {
        type: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputType).value, // will be either inc or exp
        description: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: parseFloat(document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputValue).value),
      };
    },
    addListItem: (obj, type) => {
      let html, newHtml, element;
      //create HMTL string
      if (type === "inc") {
        element = DOMStrings.incomeContainer;
        html =
          `<div class="item clearfix" id="inc-${obj.id}"> <div class="item-description">${obj.description}</div> <div class="right clearfix"> <div class="item-value">${obj.value}</div> <div class="item-delete"> <button class="item-delete-btn"> <i class="fas fa-minus"></i> </button></div> </div> </div>`;
      } else if (type === "exp") {
        element = DOMStrings.expensesContainer;
        html =
          `<div class="item clearfix" id="exp-${obj.id}"><div class="item-description">${obj.description}</div> <div class="right clearfix"> <div class="item-value">${obj.value}</div> <div class="item-delete"> <button class="item-delete-btn"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button> </div> </div> </div> </div>`;
      }
      document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
    },

    deleteListItem: (selectorID) => {
      let el = document.getElementById(selectorID);
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    },

    clearFields: () => {
      let fields = document.querySelectorAll(
        DOMStrings.inputDescription + "," + DOMStrings.inputValue
      );

      let fieldsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(fields);

      fieldsArr.forEach((current, index, array) => {
        current.value = "";
      });
      fieldsArr[0].focus();
    },
    displayBudget: (obj) => {
      document.querySelector(DOMStrings.budgetLabel).textContent = obj.budget;
      document.querySelector(DOMStrings.incomeLabel).textContent = obj.totalInc;
      document.querySelector(DOMStrings.expensesLabel).textContent = obj.totalExp;
    },
    displayMonth: () => {
      let now, year, month, months;
      now = new Date();
      months = [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December",
      ];
      month = now.getMonth();
      year = now.getFullYear();
      document.querySelector(DOMStrings.dateLabel).textContent = months[month] + ", " + year;
    },

    getDOMStrings: () => {
      return DOMStrings;
    },
  };
})();

//GLOBAL APP CONTROLLER

const controller = (function (budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {
  setupEventListeners = () => {
    let DOM = UICtrl.getDOMStrings();
    document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener("click", ctrlAddItem);

    document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
      if (event.keycode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
        ctrlAddItem();
      }
    });
    document.querySelector(DOM.container).addEventListener("click", ctrlDeleteItem);
  };
  updateBudget = () => {
    //Calculate Budget
    budgetCtrl.calculateBudget();
    //Return the budget
    let budget = budgetCtrl.getBudget();
    //display in the UI budget
    UICtrl.displayBudget(budget);
  };
  ctrlAddItem = () => {
    // Get the field input data
    let input = UICtrl.getInput();

    if (input.description !== "" && !isNaN(input.value) && input.value > 0) {
      let newItem = budgetCtrl.addItem(input.type, input.description, input.value);

      // add the item to the UI
      UICtrl.addListItem(newItem, input.type);
      //clear fields
      UICtrl.clearFields();
      //calculate the budget
      updateBudget();
    }
  };

  ctrlDeleteItem = (event) => {
    let itemID, splitID, type, ID;

    itemID = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;

    if (itemID) {
      splitID = itemID.split("-");
      type = splitID[0];
      ID = parseInt(splitID[1]);

      // delete the item from the data sctructure
      budgetCtrl.deleteItem(type, ID);
      //delete the item from UI
      UICtrl.deleteListItem(itemID);
      //update budget
      updateBudget();
    }
  };

  return {
    init: () => {
      console.log("App is initiateted!");
      UICtrl.displayMonth();
      UICtrl.displayBudget({
        budget: 0,
        totalInc: 0,
        totalExp: 0,
      });
      setupEventListeners();
    },
  };
})(budgetController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

```css
/* General */

:root {
  --primary-color: #dcdcdc;
  --dark-color: #141414;
  --contrast-color: #3aa9e0;
  --filling-color: #ff5049;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.red {
  color: var(--filling-color) !important;
}

.red-focus:focus {
  border: 1px solid var(--filling-color) !important;
}

/* Text customisation */
.budget div {
  color: var(--dark-color);
}

/* general styling */

.container-top {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.budget {
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin: auto 15px;
}
.budget-value {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.budget-income,
.budget-expenses {
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.budget-income {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: var(--contrast-color);
}

.budget-expenses {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: var(--filling-color);
}
.budget-income-text,
.budget-expenses-text {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.budget-income-value,
.budget-expenses-value {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  float: left;
}
.add {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.add-container {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.add-type {
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: border 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.add-description,
.add-value {
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add-description {
  width: 250px;
}

.add-value {
  width: 70px;
}
.add-btn {
  background-color: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 26px;
}

.add-type:focus,
.add-description:focus,
.add-value:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid var(--dark-color);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container-main {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto 2vh;
  height: 67vh;
}

.income {
  color: var(--dark-color);
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
.expenses {
  color: var(--dark-color);
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 5x;
  margin: auto 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--dark-color);
  margin: auto;
}

.item:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.item-description {
  float: left;
}

.item-value {
  float: left;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
.income-title,
.income .item-value,
.income .item-delete-btn {
  color: #28b9b5;
}

.expenses-title,
.expenses .item-value,
.expenses .item-delete-btn {
  color: #ff5049;
}

.item-delete {
  float: left;
}

.item-delete-btn {
  font-size: 15px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  display: none;
}

.item-delete-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.item-delete-btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.item:hover .item-delete-btn {
  display: block;
}
.item:hover .item-value {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}
.item:hover .item-ercentage {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f7d4881d9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Budgeten</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-top">
        <header>
            <div class="budget">
                <div class="budget-title">
                    Available Budget in <span class="budget-title-month">%Month%</span>:
                </div>

                <div class="budget-value">+ 1,234.5</div>

                <div class="budget-income clearfix">
                    <div class="budget-income-text">In</div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="budget-income-value ">+ 1,234.5</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="budget-expenses clearfix">
                    <div class="budget-expenses-text">Out</div>
                    <div class="right clearfix">
                        <div class="budget-expenses-value">- 1,234.5</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <main>
            <div class="add-new">
                <div class="add-container">
                    <select class="add-type">
                    <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
                    <option value="exp">-</option>
                    <input type="text" class="add-description" placeholder="Add description">
                    <input type="number" class="add-value" placeholder="Value">
                    <button class="add-btn"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-main clearfix">
                
                    <div class="income">
                        <h2 class="income-title">Income</h2>
                        
                        <div class="income-list">
                                <!-- <div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">
                                <div class="item-description">Salary</div>
                                <div class="right clearfix">
                                    <div class="item-value">+ 2,100.00</div>
                                    <div class="item-delete">
                                        <button class="item-delete-btn">
                                            <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item clearfix" id="income-1">
                                <div class="item-description">Sold car</div>
                                <div class="right clearfix">
                                    <div class="item-value">+ 1,500.00</div>
                                    <div class="item-delete">
                                        <button class="item-delete-btn"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> -->
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
               
                    
                    <div class="expenses">
                        <h2 class="expenses-title">Expenses</h2>
                        
                        <div class="expenses-list">

                                <!-- <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-0">
                                <div class="item-description">Apartment rent</div>
                                <div class="right clearfix">
                                    <div class="item-value">- 900.00</div>
                                    <div class="item-delete">
                                        <button class="item-delete-btn"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-1">
                                <div class="item-description">Grocery shopping</div>
                                <div class="right clearfix">
                                    <div class="item-value">- 435.28</div>
                                    <div class="item-percentage">10%</div>
                                    <div class="item-delete">
                                        <button class="item-delete-btn"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> -->
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                </div> 
            </div>        
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Arthur! It turned out that I've accidently doubled up files and posted the wrong link from git. My question sadly remains because I didn't realize my mistake last night